# Need to access a variable from main.js file to service file in node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am creating socket.io variable "io" in my main.js file.like following.

```
var server = https.createServer(secureOptions, svrMain);

server.listen(portNumber);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('join', function (data) {
   socket.join(data.email);

        console.log("group created" , data.email);
    });
});
```

I need to access io variable from another service like below.

//service.js

```
var inDeliveryInfo = dataObj["DeliveryInfo"];
var userEmail = inDeliveryInfo["UserEmail"];
var DeviceId = inDeliveryInfo["DeviceId"];
var DeliveredTime = inDeliveryInfo["DeliveredTime"];

if(userEmail != null ) {
    io.to(userEmail).emit('email_msg', {'msg' : "successfully delivered message to" +" "+ DeviceId + "at" + DeliveredTime});
}
```

How to access this io from main.js to service.js

Comment: In service.js you can get the socket module. use the below code in the service js : var io = require('socket.io')

Comment: no i want to access io var from another service.i have found the solution.commenting answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.As i made var io as global variable.
like below.

global.io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

now i can access io from another service.